# Wiki Building Software/App for Tablet

Tags: android, ios, wiki

One thing I like doing at home when working on some personal creative projects is to use a Wiki to collate all the lore, so I have easy reference to it when my memory fails me. At home I currently use MediaWiki on a WAMP server.

However, I have been setting up my tablets so I can continue this kind of work when I don't have access to my PC. One of the problems is that my memory can still fail me, and when this happens I tend to hit a roadblock (eg. when writing a Nanoha fan fiction I would have to stop when I am about to have Alicia explain why Death still exists in Al-Hazard when Trishia resurrected Lutecia and Alicia herself has been resurrected, unable to remember if this has been explained before, I normally have to stop until I can confirm it).

So I thought I should look into seeing if there was a Wiki Creation App for iOS of Android which I can use as a mobile repository of my home Wiki

### Requirements

- **Offline** - as not all the time I will have access to the Internet
- **No Logon/registration with third party** - while this should be a given with my Offline requirement Wattpad on iOS does require you to create an account and advertises that you can read books from them while offline.

  - If iOS then it should be fine to just use my Apple Login
  - If Android it should be free from any login given that Android Apps can be installed without the Google Store (so i have been told)

### Optional

- **Free** - I would rather it to be free as Mediawiki on my PC is free, then again so is OpenOffice and I still had to pay for a decent word processor on my iPad
- **PC Text Backup/Restore** - I would like to backup the Wiki to a format which I can store on the PC, mainly because then I can then develop a tool to update MediaWiki on Wamp or generate a Backup from MediaWiki and restore the tablet Wiki based off that. In the absence of this, I can use my word processor to store every wiki page and just copy and paste.

Comment: I've not yet used any myself (though playing with the thought), but there are several [Wiki editors](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_office#group_106) and [Markdown Editors](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_office#group_107) available for Android which you might wish to check (I've put this as a comment as I cannot give a clear recommendation, leaving the "check" to you in this case; still, I hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

### [TiddlyWiki](http://tiddlywiki.com/)

TiddlyWiki is a single webpage wiki which runs under most browsers. That makes it very flexible. There are two ways to run it on Android:

1. Using the Firefox extension. Instructions for that are on the homepage or in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iikkv9orGGI)
2. Using the [AndTidWiki Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.mgsimon.android.andtidwiki)

Features:

- **Offline**. All information are stored in a single local `html` file
- **No registration required**. It's ready to edit as soon as you download it
- **Free of charge**
- **Easy to backup and sync**: Since it's all in a single file, you can synchornize it with a PC over Wi-fi or using a cloud service. You can store versions of the files using a revision control software, or by editing the wiki with [TiddlyDesktop](https://github.com/Jermolene/TiddlyDesktop) which automatically saves backups

Comment: This is a good choice +1